# Write to Yaml file based on excel

Tags: powershell, yaml, powerbi-embedded

I've got an YAML file that contains information from a Powerbi file. we need to add some of the metadata like Tags (we're talking here about tens of dosens if not hundreds.
what I thought is to extract this in an excel - write it there and then inject it back to yaml.
Any way to do that automatically?

here's a sample:

processTime: 08-06-22

- report:

  - reportId: 34lkn34l5k
  - reportVersion: '1'
  - reportDeveloper: dev1
  - reportDomain: ''
  - linkedDataset: dataset
  - filters:

    - filterId: Filtera1

      - table: DIM_E
      - column: CLIENT
      - type: Categorical
      - metadata:

        - label: Company
        - tags: []
    - filterId: Filter2

      - table: DIM_E
      - column: DEPARTMENT
      - type: Categorical
      - metadata:

        - label: Department
        - tags: []
- pages:

  - pageId: ReportSection
  - displayName: test
  - visuals:

    - visualId: 9dc8
    - visualType: donutChart
    - measures:  Headcount
    - columns:   - EMPLO
    - title: Headcount
    - metadata:

      - label: ''
      - tags: []
      - domain: diversity
      - hierarchy: []

Comment: You can use the `ImportExcel` module to work easily with Excel documents in PowerShell. There may be other modules to work with yaml files but I'm not aware of them.

Comment: Excel is propably not the right tool for this job. Excel works with tabular data, while YAML is a structured format. I suggest to use a YAML parser module for PowerShell and manipulate the data directly in PowerShell.